# Access 2010: criteria Not "a" or Not "b" get ignored

Tags: microsoft-access

Access 2010 problem with criteria

The following works:

- "a"
- "b"
- "a" or "b"
- Not "a"
- Not "b"

The following does not work

- Not "a" or Not "b"

Here the criteria get ignored completely.

Why is that?

I’m not looking for a workaround, just an explanation.

Comment: If it is A then it is not B, and if it is B it is not A, so it would always go true ... do you mean not a and not b ?

Answer (score 1):

The criteria isn't being *ignored*, but rather the criteria is **always validated**.

Consider that:

- `(not "a")` matches anything not equal to `"a"` (hence this will include `"b"`)
- `(not "b")` matches anything not equal to `"b"` (hence this will include `"a"`)

As such, `(not "a") or (not "b")` will always return all records.

Another way to think about this is that:

```
(not "a") or (not "b")
```

is equivalent to:

```
not ("a" and "b")
```

And since something cannot be both `"a"` and `"b"` at the same time, this will always be validated.

---

I suspect that you actually require the logic:

```
(not "a") and (not "b")
```

Which may be equivalently written:

```
not ("a" or "b")
```

That it to say, neither `"a"` nor `"b"`